# Pass arguments from one function to another

Tags: javascript

Here I have been developing a `chat` application. Here I want to load `chat messages` according to the `email address` of the user. Here I want to pass `email address` to the backend.

In `javascript`, I want to pass email to `LoadChat` function from `(".friend").each(function(x){`.
It shows in `console.log` in `LoadChat` function, immediatetly it becomes `undefined`.

Here is the `Javascript` code

```
     $(".friend").each(function(x){     
          $(this).click(function(){
                        
              var name = $(this).find("p strong").html();
              var email = $(this).find("p span").html();
              var id = $(this).find("p spans").html();
                    
              LoadChat(email);
                                                
              $("#profile p").html(name);
              $("#profile span").html(email);           
              
              $(".message").not(".right").find("img").attr("src", $(clone).attr("src"));                                    
              $('#friendslist').fadeOut();
              $('#chatview').fadeIn();
                 
          setTimeout(function(){
          $('#chatview').fadeOut();
          $('#friendslist').fadeIn();               
       }, 50);            
    });              
   });
});
```

Here is the other `LoadChat` function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    LoadChat();
    
    setInterval(function () {
        LoadChat();
    }, 1000);

    function LoadChat(email) {
        
console.log(email);
$.post('handlers/messages.php?action=getMessages&email='+email, function (response) {

    var scrollpos = $('#chat-messages').scrollTop();
    var scrollpos = parseInt(scrollpos) + 420;
    var scrollHeight = $('#chat-messages').prop('scrollHeight');

    $('#chat-messages').html(response);
    if (scrollpos < scrollHeight){

    } else{
        $('#chat-messages').scrollTop($('#chat-messages').prop('scrollHeight'));
    }

})

}

    $('form').submit(function () {
        //alert('form is submit jquery');
        var message = $('.textarea').val();

        if ($(".textarea").val()) {

        $.post('handlers/messages.php?action=sendMessage&message='+message, function (response) {
            //alert(response);
            if (response==1){
                LoadChat();
                document.getElementById('msgform').reset();
            }
        });

    } else {

        myFunction();

}
        return false;

    })
</script>
```

Any help may highly appreciated

Comment: In LoadChat function, `function LoadChat(email) {`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `LoadChat()` without arguments in several places. Calling a function without arguments will set its arguments to `undefined` if it has any. If you want `email` to be set, provide it as an argument to the function call.

```js
function LoadChat(email) {
  console.log(email);
}

// call without arguments
LoadChat();

// call with arguments
LoadChat("john.doe@example.com");
```

Comment: Another thing is I want to pass the `email` variable to `$('form').submit(function () {` to send the `email` to `php`. How it is possible?

Comment: Add it to the query parameter or body of your request to the server, for example: `$.post("handlers/messages.php", {action: "sendMessage", message: message, email: email}, function (response) { /* ... */ })`

Comment: I mean, how can I pass `email`  to capture in `submit function` to send

Comment: You'll have to think about what you want. How does the form know what email to pass to the server? Does the user provide the email through the form? Can it be pulled from the page? If the JavaScript is generated by the same server you could define it globally. For chat applications often a session is used, which is saved and send through a cookie. The server can the deduce the email from the session.

Comment: Pulling from the page is most of the time not optimal. The question is how did the data come there to start with? If you find where the data is set you might be able to also supply it to your submit event. For example if it is generated by php with for example the template `<p><?= htmlspecialchars($user_email) $></p>` Then you might be able to set the the `email` in JavaScript in a similar fashion. `const email = <?= json_encode($user_email) ?>`

Comment: There are list of name of `users`. Just I clicked it, then it should be take the `email` of the user.

Comment: when use this `const email = <?= json_encode($user_email) ?>`, it take the last `email` of the `user`, not particular `user`

Comment: I want this, this is the email set to variable `var email = $(this).find("p span").html();` in `$(".friend").each(function(x){` function. Now I want to tranfer this to `$('form').submit(function () {`